# Composer Install/Update stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

Suddenly my Composer has stopped working.

Whenever I run `composer update`, it doesn't progress after this:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
>       Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

I tried another Laravel project, that project's Composer was working

I cleared the cache, and also ran this command `rm -rf ~/.composer/cache`

Nothing seems to happen. I moved `composer.lock` to a different folder, deleted from the current project and ran the commands again, but no luck

Here is my `composer.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "nesbot/carbon": "~1.14",
        "venturecraft/revisionable": "~1.8",
        "doctrine/dbal": "v2.4.2",
        "zizaco/entrust": "dev-laravel-5",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "~1.0",
        "sofa/revisionable": "~1.0@dev",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.0.0",
        "monolog/monolog": "^1.15",
        "jenssegers/agent": "^2.2",
        "php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser": "^2.1",
        "messaged/php-mime-mail-parser": "^1.0",
        "willdurand/email-reply-parser": "^2.4",
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "~2.0.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Validations\\": "app/Validations"
        },
        "files": [
            "app/Support/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\"",
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: usually it takes some time at this step `Updating dependencies (including require-dev)` did you give it a minute or three? What happens if you run `composer install` instead of update?

Comment: I agree with Peh- give it more time. If you give it enough time it'll show the error or work.

Comment: I waited 20 minutes. Same two lines, nothing else. No errors, no progress.

Comment: And already tried composer install -v and composer install. Just those two lines. Installing instead of Updating.

Comment: Could you try running composer for this project on another machine? I pulled your composer.json file, had to get rid of the App\Validations psr-4 call and the app/support/helpers file call and the TestCase classmap, because I have none of them on my machine... however, when I ran the install I got this error: http://devimg.next-www.com/20151203105910-001.png Do you have ext-mailparse installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have ext-mailparse.

Comment: You can remove all the mail-parser packages from the require list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some Tests and it looks like these two packages *in combination* cause the problem:

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "~1.0",
```

They install properly each for itself but not together. I used a fresh Laravel 5.1 install for testing (`composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`). After adding only these two packages to the `composer.json` Composer is stuck at

> Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

If you remove one of them your `composer update` runs fine. I don't know anything about these two packages but the combination definitely crashes Composer even in `-verbose` mode.

---

The crashing `composer.json` as minimal example:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.1.*",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "~3.0",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4.0",
        "phpspec/phpspec": "~2.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Validations\\": "app/Validations"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "classmap": [
            "tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled",
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "pre-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan clear-compiled"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "php artisan optimize"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "php artisan key:generate"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I removed "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v2": "~1.0", and it worked. Thanks a lot.